# What game am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

Can you work out what game I am? (My original puzzle):

Head hung low in… (5) - Best card of the deck (3)

Written much by peer and shakes, often read for the love it makes (6) - Certainly not pretty after a car crash (6)

Elegant flower and popular where there is red light (5) - Ferocious flying beast of ancient times (7)

Spins then flies (10) - 10 squared over 10 cubed (7)

Useful after a long walk (8) - Country with much rain and a long reign (7)

Deviating from the norm (8) - Impregnable (4)

A quality of an intelligent mind (9) - ‘Pokemon___Balls’ (6)

Every movie needs one (8) -  ‘sickness unto health’, place (8)

Famous child author’s river of ___ (9) -  Only a tad icy (5)

Hint 1

> The Alphabet order

Hint 2

> It is a card game

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer. The clue refers to:

> The first letters of every 2nd question ascend alphabetically. Also worth noting the rhyming connection for pairs 1 and 2 , although 4, 7 and 9 don't seem to follow this pattern.

1

> Disgrace / ace

2

> Sonnet / bonnet

3

> Roses?? / Cyclops

4

> Helicopter / decimal

5

> ? / England

6

> Abnormal / Fort

7

> Intellect / ...Go Poke?

8

> Montages? / Hospital

9

> Chocolate / icing?

Comment: An improvement from the other answer but still mistaken in some areas, you have the alphabet order correct.

Answer (score 0):

Partials:

Head hung low in… (5)

> shame

Best card of the deck (3)

> ace

Written much by peer and shakes, often read for the love it makes (6)

> poetry

Certainly not pretty after a car crash (6)

> fender? (fender bender)

Spins then flies (10)

> helicopter

Country with much rain and a long reign (7)

> Britain/England, possibly

Deviating from the norm (8)

> uncommon/abnormal/atypical/peculiar (i could probably go on :P)

Impregnable (4)

> safe

Every movie needs one (8)

> director

Only a tad icy (5)

> chill? frost?

Not sure what to do with each pair (admittedly I only have one pair)

Comment: Half correct so far let me add a hint that might make your see your mistakes.

Comment: May I suggest: pair 2 is fbaarg, obaarg